# To get GAL of non default address book from multiple accounts in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I have two domain accounts configured in my outlook, for example xxx@domain1.com and yyy@domain2.com.

There are 2 address books (Please refer to the picture attached). I want to show user to SelectNameDialog by adding the recipients from non-default account's address book. But it adds the names to the selectnamedialog from the default address book and displays.

C# code :

```
Outlook.SelectNamesDialog snd = app.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog();![AddressBook Select name dialog][1]
```

How to get non-default account’s address book programmatically.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz7HC.png): [image: Address Book SelectNameDialog]

Comment: Do you want to show the other GAL to the user? Or iterate through its entries programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Outlook automatically selects the relevant address book based om the currently active store (Ctrl + Shift + B to show the address book, Tools | Options | "When Opening the address book, show this address list first", make sure "Choose automatically" is selected).

Programmatically, use the  [SelectNamesDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176400%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) object and its  [InitialAddressList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176179(v=office.12).aspx) property.